# show/hide field based on user's attribute

Tags: 7, forms, entities

how do I show/hide field of the form based on currently logged in user's field?
my users' profiles have `start_date_field`.

my form has 5 questions:

```
day_1_activity -> drop down
day_2_activity -> drop down
day_3_activity -> drop down
day_4_activity -> drop down
day_5_activity -> drop down
```

Now I would like to do a simple comparison:

`start_date_field` of logged in user with `current_date`.

if `start_date_field = current_date` show `day_1_activity` only.

if `start_date_field + 1 = current_date` show `day_1_activity` and `day_2_activity` only.

...

Comment: are you referring to a specific form in Drupal or a custom form that you've created?

Comment: custom that I have created using entityforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to hide all questions drop down fields by setting `#access` to `FALSE` then show each field according to the condition.

You should use [`hook_form_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to alter your `entityform` form.

```
function MODULE_NAME_form_MACHINE_NAME_entityform_edit_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  global $user; // to get the current user uid

  // hide all drop down
  $form['field_day_1_activity']['#access'] = FALSE;
  $form['field_day_2_activity']['#access'] = FALSE;
  $form['field_day_3_activity']['#access'] = FALSE;
  $form['field_day_4_activity']['#access'] = FALSE;
  $form['field_day_5_activity']['#access'] = FALSE;

  // load user
  $account = user_load($user->uid);

  // get user start_date_field value
  $user_start_date = $account->field_start_date_field['und'][0]['value'];

  // show question drop down based on the condition.
  switch ($user_start_date) {
    case date('Y-m-d'):
      $form['field_day_1_activity']['#access'] = TRUE;
      break;
    case date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day')):
      $form['field_day_1_activity']['#access'] = TRUE;
      $form['field_day_2_activity']['#access'] = TRUE;
      break;
    case date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+2 day')):
      $form['field_day_1_activity']['#access'] = TRUE;
      $form['field_day_2_activity']['#access'] = TRUE;
      $form['field_day_3_activity']['#access'] = TRUE;
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: looks like exactly what I needed. If I were to make it more flexible it the way that I would be able to choose, in the code of this module, which forms should be altered, how would I go about it?

Comment: worked great! just needed to change `$user_start_date = $account->field_start_date_field['und'][0]['value'];` to `$user_start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($account->field_start_date['und'][0]['value']));` as it was giving me time as well time as well **00:00:00**

Comment: and `strtotime('+1 day')` to `strtotime('-1 day')` etc.. Thanks a lot for this! I you wouldn't mind helping me with my first comment or directing to literature that will help it would be very appreciated

Comment: regarding to your first comment; mean you want an admin section to configure which forms should have similar functionality?!

Comment: yes. I've altered the code above to suit my requirements and now all forms with different fields, days etc work great and its very flexible as well. It would be nice to add radio button in entity form settings (add and edit) to say (run this code on this form) yes/no. Thanks a lot again for your help - really helped me understand basic of hooks

Comment: My friend, your request is so detailed; so I recommend you to submit your question, in a question post not in a comment.